# Reading a URLLIB response

Tags: python

The response I get will either be t or f. No html tags or anything just t or f.

```
print("'" + str(response.read()) + "'")
resp = response.read()
if "t" in resp:
        print("true")
if "f" in resp:
        print("false")
```

No matter what I'm not getting either true or false.
Example output: `'f'` no true or false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to store a response's `read()`ing in a variable because you can only read it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a response's read()ing in a variable because you can only read it once. –  Navith 5 mins ago
Thanks solved it!